# Magento - remove setTemplate action from block

Tags: magento, templates, magento-layout-xml, layout-xml

I'm extending the CatalogSearch/Advanced/Result block which in its layout XML file calls:

`<reference name="root">`

`<action method="setTemplate"> ...`

to set a specific root template when this block is being displayed.  I'd like to undo this via my own xml file.  I can "undo" this by simply setting the template to the default root template in my own xml file, however, what I'm looking for is a way to unset the template so that I don't have to specify which root template to use and simply use the default root template (as if the setTemplate statement didn't exist in the CatalogSearch/Advanced/Result block's layout xml).

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this without a class rewrite or without some custom PHP calculation via helper & invoked in layout XML.